# Why is "OR" query 120x slower than two single-condition queries in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql-performance

A single query, which I thought would save time:

```
SELECT PeoplePair.id, PeoplePair.date_created, People.id
FROM PeoplePair
INNER JOIN People ON (PeoplePair.person2_id = People.id)
INNER JOIN People P2 ON (PeoplePair.person1_id = P2.id)
WHERE (People.town_id = 24728 OR P2.town_id = 24728);
```

Takes about 60 seconds to execute

Instead, doing two separate queries takes < 0.5 seconds total

```
SELECT PeoplePair.id, PeoplePair.date_created, People.id
FROM PeoplePair
INNER JOIN People ON (PeoplePair.person1_id = People.id)
WHERE People.town_id = 24728;

SELECT PeoplePair.id, PeoplePair.date_created, People.id
FROM PeoplePair
INNER JOIN People ON (PeoplePair.person2_id = People.id)
WHERE People.town_id = 24728;
```

And for fun, here's a screenshot of load dropping after switching to the second query in my app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would think about following options:

I. rewrite query using following way (assuming that `PeoplePair.person1_id` and `PeoplePair.person2_id` are protected by FK and you do not need to retrieve information about both sides of `PeoplePair` relation)

```
select pp.*
from PeoplePair pp,
     People p
where (pp.person1_id = p.id
    or pp.person2_id = p.id)
  and (p.town_id = 24728);
```

II. switch to [double-entry bookkeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping) pattern i.e. duplicate each (person1_id, person2_id) pair in `PeoplePair` table as (person2_id, person1_id) - in that case the query will contain single join only and no OR's.

The technique, you have started using, is actually called [OR Expansion](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/optimizer-transformations-or-expansion) - some DB's support it, PostgreSQL - does not.

Answer (score -1):

The difference in performance between combining conditions using OR in a single query versus using separate queries with individual conditions in the WHERE clause can arise due to how the optimizer processes and executes these queries.
When you use separate queries with individual conditions, the query optimizer can focus on optimizing each query independently.

Explore the reasons behind this difference:

- Ensure that the columns used in the OR conditions are properly indexed.
- Make sure that table statistics are up-to-date.

Examine the execution plans for both the combined OR query and the separate queries. This can help identify which parts of the query are causing performance issues.

Comment: Did this come from chatgpt?

Comment: Yes... but it make sense